# ASP.NET masterpage :- how to remove usercontrol from masterpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a `masterpage` which has a `usercontrol` (`changecity.ascx`) on it. Now I am using same master page on 2 aspx pages:

1. selectcity.aspx
2. signup.aspx

But I want to show `changecity.ascx` on `selectcity.aspx` only.

I can set it`s visibility from child pages but I don't want to do that because page events of`changecity.ascx` were still firing.

I want it to be completely removed from `masterpage` so that no events of `changecity.ascx` should be fired.

What i did so far :---
  I removed the control from `masterpage` in `signup.aspx`'s `preinit` event. but page life cycle events of `changecity.ascx` are still firing. How can I prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load your control in codebehind and add it to the page. If you just try an if in the .aspx it will be renderd but just not outputted.

aspx:

```
<asp:placeholder id="changeCityControl" runat="server" />
```

Codebehind:

```
ChangeCityControl ccControl = (ChangeCityControl)LoadControl("/changecity.ascx")
if (renderChangeCityControl){    
    changeCityControl.Controls.Add(ccControl);
}
```

See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf(v=vs.110).aspx) microsoft page for details.

Comment: i will check this. I think this might help

Comment: How will this control take it`s place on the master page. Do I need to place it inside a panel

Comment: Have you tried to add the control in the OnInit (Page_Init)?

Comment: Is your control null after LoadControl has loaded your control? Try to use LoadControl(Type, Object[]) instead, where Type is the type of your control and Object[] the parameters to pass. It may be, that the path is not correct

Comment: Also, in the microsoft page linked in the answer, they use it in Page_Init:"When you load a control into a container control, the container raises all of the added control's events until it has caught up to the current event. However, the added control does not catch up with postback data processing. For an added control to participate in postback data processing, including validation, the control must be added in the Init event rather than in the Load event."